# Does a unipotent transformation preserve covolume?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, discrete-geometry

Let $S\subset \mathbb{R}^d$ and define $v(S)$ to be the volume of the set $(S+\mathbb{Z}^d)\cap [0,1]^d$ (where $[0,1]^d$ is the unit cube $[0,1]\times [0,1] \times...\times [0,1]$).  Let $T: \mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$ be a linear transformation of determinant one whose only eigenvalue is one.  Is it necessarily true that $v(S)=v(T(S))$?

Comment: The unipotence of $T$ is equivalent to the condition you already have. In any case, I'm fairly sure your statement holds whenever the absolute value of the determinant of $T$ is $1$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thanks! I guess I meant for the first condition to include rotations, somehow. Also it doesn't seem to be true in $\mathbb{R}^2$ for T=diag(2, 1/2) and $S=I^2$.

Comment: Note that rotations have two complex-conjugate eigenvalues of magnitude $1$.  Also, interesting counterexample, I suppose I didn't account for overlap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $S=[0,1/2]\times[0,2]$ and $T=\begin{bmatrix}1&1/2\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$. Then $v(S)=1/2$ but $v(T(S))=1$.